# Python max on potential same values

Tags: python, comparison, max

I have a problem with the max() function of python. 
Here's my situation :

```
results = {'left' : leftKeyCounter, 'right' : rightKeyCounter, 'front' : frontKeyCounter, 'back' : backKeyCounter}

finalScore = max(results, key=results.get)

print(finalScore, 'wins')
```

The problem I have is to make if conditions on what's happening with my results. Let's say, I have

```
results = {'left' : 1, 'right' : 1, 'front' : 1, 'back': 0}
```

The fact that he will return 'front wins' on this is completely random, and I need to filter over that result. (or before?) 
So that if it's a draw between the 2 highest results, that he cancels it (for example)

What could be the easiest way to make that possible ? I looked into the "counter" but that doesn't achieve what I intend to do here, as my numbers are already packed and I just need to compare 4 values, without any tie between the 2 highests value.

Thanks a lot ! :-)

Comment: So if your dictionary had the values (3, 1, 3, 2), you'd want the function to return 2, because of the tie for 3?

Comment: No, I wan't him to recognize that there is a tie, and return something from that (for example : "TIE")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With one pass over the dictionary you can figure out the correct result. Reverse the keys with the values and keep a track of the highest score. If there is more than one items for the highest score, you can return a custom message.

In reversing, you can't simply do `{value: key for key, value in results.items()}`, because if two values are the same, they will overwrite the previous one. So you have to keep the results in a list. Credits to chepner for `scores.setdefault()`. He also suggested that the same can be achieved with [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
def calculate_winner(d):
    scores = {}
    high_score = 0
    for key, value in d.items():
        scores.setdefault(value, []).append(key)
        if value > high_score:
            high_score = value
    results = scores[high_score]
    if len(results) == 1:
        return results[0]
    else:
        return 'TIE', results
```

Example:

```
>>> calculate_winner(results)
('TIE', ['front', 'right', 'left'])
```

**Edit**: If you have a small dictionary, you can achieve the same result with fewer lines of code by doing two passes: one to find the max score and one to filter out the winners.

```
def calcaluate_winner(d):
    max_value = max(d.values())
    winners = [key for key in d if d[key] == max_value]
    if len(winners) == 1:
        return winners[0]
    else:
        return 'TIE', winners
```

Comment: I give it a try, but I think `max_value = max(values)` returns only ONE final result, randomly into the tie, I'll tell you the result !

Comment: I'm struggling making this code work, returning me things like :
` AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'count' `

Comment: If you want all the keys involved in a tie, you can get them with `[key for key in d if d[key] == max_value]`.

Comment: That is exactly what I intended to make ! I was looking for an easier way to do, as Python seamed very powerful to me, but I guess some things need to be done with some more lines ! 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ThaoD5 You can do it with fewer lines of code: `max_value = max(results.values()); {key for key in results if results[key] == max_value}`, but that requires two passes over the dictionary. If you guarantee the dictionary to be short, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You can replace the `try/except` statement with `scores.setdefault(value, []).append(key)`. Or, use `scores = defaultdict(list)` in place of a regular `dict`; then `scores[value].append(key)` will always succeed.